# Program is working wrong while melody playing

Tags: arduino-uno

My robot working fine but when I added buzzer and melody into code then is something wrong. Melody is playing when accelerometer is activated but rest of the code need to wait to end of melody. I want to play melody in background when program works. How to do it? There is my code:

```
#include <RedBot.h>
#include <RedBotSoftwareSerial.h>
RedBotAccel accel;
RedBotMotors motors;
int CM;        
long CZAS;     
bool started = false;
const int buzzer = A0;

int shortTone = 80;
int longTone = 200;
int standardDelay = 50;
int delayBetweenBars = 50;

void setup() 
{  
   Serial.begin(9600);
   accel.enableBump();
   accel.setBumpThresh(150);
   pinMode(A2, OUTPUT);  //Trig
   pinMode(A3, INPUT);   //Echo 
   pinMode(buzzer, OUTPUT);  //Buzzer
}


void pomiar_odleglosci()
{
   digitalWrite(A2, HIGH);      
   delayMicroseconds(10);
   digitalWrite(A2, LOW);
   CZAS = pulseIn(A3, HIGH);
   CM = CZAS / 58;                
}

void loop(){



   while (!accel.checkBump() && !started) delay(100);
   started = true;

   if(started = true)
   {   DarudeSandstorm();
   }


   pomiar_odleglosci();               
   Serial.print("Odleglosc: ");      
   Serial.print(CM);
   Serial.println(" cm");

   if(CM>10)                 
   {
      motors.drive(100);
   }
   else     
   {
      motors.drive(-100);
      delay(400);
      motors.stop();

      delay(400);

      motors.rightMotor(100);
      delay(700);
      motors.stop();

      motors.drive(100);
   }

}
//melody
```

Comment: Define wrong. Also, links to code are not wanted. Post your code in your question and format it correctly. Tell us what you expect to happen, and what *actually* happens.

Comment: Where does the melody play? At the `DarudeSandstorm` function? Where is it defined? Please provide a link for the red robot includes, so that we can check them.

Comment: This is all code: https://pastebin.com/aihBQZT1 , and this is library for redbot.h: https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_RedBot_Arduino_Library/blob/master/src/RedBot.h

Answer (score 1):

You are using delay() in many parts of your code, which makes it very trick. I see a couple of possibilities here:

1 - if you have extra time and patience, get rid of all delays and find your around it counting millis() or some similar technique.

2 - if you have some extra bucks, get another controller just to play the melody, an ATtiny85 should be cheap and practical for this.

There is also the super-lazy, almost-no-work-at-all, relatively cheap solution: use a small media/MP3 player module, which also would allow you to have more than one melody and eventually adtiional noises.

Comment: So for example how to change delay(1000); to millis?

Comment: look at the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example code in the Arduino IDE